# How to compare two variables in php

Tags: php, mysql

In my case ... one variable is coming from other page through get variable 
And i have to compare this with existing variable of my choice
but my technique is not working
Help me if someone can.
I want to compare coming get variable with nursery..but when i try this could not ...
thanks in advance

```
<?php
include('config.php');
  $results =@$_GET['results'];

  $id =$_GET['id'];

 if ($results=="Nursery")
{
$qqqs = mysql_query("select * from result where u_id='$id'   sc='Nursery' ");

$rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($qqqs);
$a=$rows['u_id'];
$b=$rows['name'];
$c=$rows['fname'];
$d=$rows['reg'];
$e=$rows['sc'];
$f=$rows['ss'];
$g=$rows['se'];
$h=$rows['e1'];
$i=$rows['u1'];
$j=$rows['m1'];
$k=$rows['s1'];
$l=$rows['ss1'];
$m=$rows['i1'];
$n=$rows['e2'];
$o=$rows['u2'];
$p=$rows['e3'];
$pp=$rows['u3'];
echo "<html>
<head>
<link href='bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css' rel='stylesheet' >
<link href='bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css'  rel='stylesheet'>
<link href='bootstrap/css/bootstrap.theme.css' rel='stylesheet' >
<link href='bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css' rel='stylesheet' >
</head>
<body>
 <table align='center' border='4' bgcolor='white' width='500' class='table table-bordered'>
 <tr>
  <td bgcolor='orange' colspan='3'><h2 align='center'>Leads Grammer School</h2></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
  <td bgcolor='yellow' colspan='3'><h2 align='center'>Academic Performance Record Year 2014</h2></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td align='right'>Student's Name:</td>
<td colspan='2'>$b</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align='right'>Father's Name:</td>
<td colspan='2'> $c</td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td align='right'>Registration NO:</td>
<td colspan='2'>$d</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align='right'>Student Class:</td>
<td colspan='2'>$e</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align='right'>Exams:</td>
<td colspan='2'>$f</td>
</tr>
 <tr bgcolor='gray'>
 <th>Subject Name</th>
 <th>Obtained Marks</th>
 <th>Grades</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <tr ><td>English(Writing)</td>
 <td> $g</td>

 </tr>
 <tr>
 <tr ><td>Urdu(Writing)</td>
 <td>$h</td>

 </tr>
 <tr>
<tr ><td>Math(Writing)</td>
 <td> $i</td>

 </tr>
<tr><th align='center' colspan='3' bgcolor='orange'>General Knowledge</th></tr>
 <tr>
 <tr ><td>Science</td>

 <td> $j</td>

</tr>
<tr>
<tr ><td>S.Studies</td>
<td>$k</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<tr ><td>Islamiat</td>
<td>$l</td>
</tr>

<tr><th align='center' colspan='3' bgcolor='orange'>Poems</th></tr>
<tr>
<tr ><td>English </td>
<td> $m</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<tr ><td>Urdu</td>
<td>$n</td>
</tr>

<tr><th align='center' colspan='3' bgcolor='orange'>Book Reading</th></tr>
<tr>
<tr><td>English </td>
<td>$o</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<tr >
<td>Urdu</td>
<td>$p</td>
</tr>";
}
?>
```

Comment: You have something missing here `where u_id='$id'   sc='Nursery'` possibly `AND` or `OR`. That error would have easily been caught had you been checking for errors.

Comment: but my if condition in not  working above

Comment: What do your PHP logs tell you? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: my if condition did not working

Comment: blank page appears when i do $result="nursery"..then result appers

Comment: Firstly, you're suppressing possible errors with the `@` symbol. Get rid of it, then add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.  Also `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`.

Comment: i have to compare it not to assign value by just = sign

Comment: You also have BAD SQL injection vulnerability and are using a deprecated MySQL library in `mysql`.  I would suggest looking at using `mysqli` or `PDO` along with parametrized prepared statements if you are just beginning to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to compare coming get variable with **nursery**

But then you are comparing with **Nursery**

```
if ($results=="Nursery")
```

Are you aware that that comparison is case-sensitive?

Also that code is poor. It should simply be

```
$results=isset($_GET['results']) ?  $_GET['results'] : NULL;
```

Do not use error suppression when you are learning something new.

And Oh, [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?s=1|15.4981)

Comment: Since you're documenting all his mistakes, his SQL call is also invalid: "select * from result where u_id='$id'   sc='Nursery' " he needs an AND in there.

Comment: @Mark Exactly, [`which was the first thing I said to the OP...`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26716992/how-to-compare-two-variables-in-php#comment42024006_26716992)

Comment: @Fred-ii- I saw, I just figured since he was shooting for a 'complete' answer he should try to stick that in there somehow.

Comment: @Mark I decided not to put in an answer, because questions like these tend to open up a proverbial "can of worms". OP just stated above *" in both it did not working"*, so am wondering why OP said that yet accepted the answer. Saw the error of his/her ways? lol I don't think so. OP is putting comments under the other answer as we speak.

Comment: @Fred-ii- That's fair enough. I don't think the OP here quite gets the idea - but I always shoot for making the best answer the most complete answer, so that subsequent readers understand that they need to take the time to debug their code and remove the 'cheap' stuff (like a bad SQL statement) before they ask a question.

Comment: No Problem.. i am just beginner and you people are just making laugh together..no matters

Comment: @Mark You and I think the same way. The more complete an answer, the better. I tend to slip in an occasional "as an insight" for potential future issues. Now OP is asking how to do it via a "switch". You see..., I was right about the "can of worms". I'm so glad I didn't put in an answer, I'd of been haggled to death lol

Comment: @UmairKhan Actually, your question could have been avoided entirely, had you read and understood how SQL and PHP work including how to debug code. Voted to close.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use the filter functions if you don't use a framework. You are putting the value from id straight into a query unescaped. That is a SQL injection waiting to happen.

```
$results = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "results", FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW);
$id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "id", FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);

if (
    0 === strcasecmp($results, "Nursery")
    && is_int($id)
) {
    $qqqs = mysql_query("select * from result where u_id='$id' AND sc='Nursery' ");

    //...
}
```

If you use integers in a query you have to KNOW they are integers. If you use strings you have to properly escape them. Or use prepared statements.

Comment: <td><a href='result.php?results=$dd && id=$u_id'  >Monthly Tests</a></td>

Comment: from it i m getting results

Comment: how can i do this by switch

Comment: @UmairKhan I'm not sure what you're asking. But you can read about switches here: php.net/switch

Comment: @UmairKhan *"how can i do this by switch"* - That should be another question entirely. You should read up on tutorials, the good and well-written ones. You ask one question after another. We are not a school.

Comment: 0h sorry.... i am struggling from morning but in vain still not been able to find the solution